# Incorrect DateFormatter result when using timeIntervalSince1970

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

When I run the following code

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
print(dateFormatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)))
```

This gets printed out: 
`01/01/1970 08:00:00`

which is supposed to be:
`01/01/1970 00:00:00`

what could be wrong?

Comment: Locale........?

Comment: Are you in the GMT+8 timezone?

Comment: So, I'm +10 hours ahead where I live and your code (once corrected) prints `01/01/1970 10:00:00` - so, it's a time zone thing

Answer (score 1):

- `Date(timeIntervalSince1970:)` creates a date relative to 00:00:00 **UTC** on 1 January 1970 by the given number of seconds.
- `DateFormatter` by default formats the date according to your local timezone.

Apparently you are in the GMT+8 timezone, so "00:00:00 UTC" is
"08:00:00" on *your* clock.

You can assign a different timezone to the date formatter if
required. To print the formatted date relative to UTC use

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0) // <--- HERE
print(dateFormatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this and you will get the date according to your TimeZone :

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
let timeZoneDifference = TimeInterval(TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT())
let date = dateFormatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0))
print(date)
let dateAccoringToMyTimeZone = dateFormatter.string(from: 
Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeZoneDifference))
print(dateAccoringToMyTimeZone)
```